# Creating MS Reader files

Tags: microsoft-word, file-format

What's the best way to create an MS Reader [.lit] file from another text document (.txt / .doc etc')?

There used to be an MS Word plugin, but it's not Office 2007 compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summed up answer seems to be [ReaderWorks](http://www.overdrive.com/readerworks/software/standard.asp) (requires annoying free-registration before being able to download).

Answer (score 0):

[A Quick Guide to Making Microsoft Reader Books](http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/reader/makingreaderbooks.htm)

> There used to be an MS Word plugin,
>   but it's not Office 2007 compatible.

oh, the [MS Word plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=F1F5A2A4-B30C-4F2B-BE85-BC9443E1BC61&displaylang=en) is still available, but it still isn't compatibe with MSO 2007, but the free version of ReaderWorks should be do the trick.

Comment: This guide is rather cluttered and doesn't seem to be completely about what it's titled actually, but it did lead me to the answer eventually.